# How to understand the recursion in a particular nested list?

Tags: python, recursion

I have been trying to get better with recursions and as an exercise I tried to create a function that returns a **sum** of all `int` elements in the following nested list: `[1, [2, 3, [4], []], [5]]`

After couple of hours I gave up and found a beautiful solution which I want to understand here.

```
def lsum(l):
    if type(l) is int:        
        return l
    elif type(l) is list and len(l) > 0:
        print l
        return lsum(l[0]) + lsum(l[1:])
    return 0
```

The function above runs and prints the following:

```
[1, [2, 3, [4], []], [5]]
[[2, 3, [4], []], [5]]
[2, 3, [4], []]
[3, [4], []]
[[4], []]
[4]
[[]]
[[5]]
[5]
```

*Question:* What I can't understand is how when our list is `[[]]` the function finds `[[5]]` since `[[]][0]` is `[]` and `[[]][1:]` is `[]`?

Comment: The `5` is found in a completely different branch of the recursion to the one the empty list `[]` is considered in.

Comment: please explain why you think that "function finds `[[5]]`" when it examines `[[]]`.

Comment: branch? now I am even more confused :)

Comment: a recursive process can be visualized as a tree where branches are steps of the process. in other words, each function invocation is a branch in this tree. hence the term "branch".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This modification may help you to understand what's happening:

```
def lsum(l, depth=0):
    print depth, l
    if type(l) is int:        
        return l
    elif type(l) is list and len(l) > 0:
        return lsum(l[0], depth+1) + lsum(l[1:], depth+1)
    return 0
```

In use:

```
>>> lsum([1, [2, 3, [4], []], [5]])
0 [1, [2, 3, [4], []], [5]]
1 1
1 [[2, 3, [4], []], [5]]
2 [2, 3, [4], []]
3 2
3 [3, [4], []]
4 3
4 [[4], []]
5 [4]
6 4
6 []
5 [[]]
6 []
6 []
2 [[5]]
3 [5]
4 5
4 []
3 []
15
```

To look at it another way:

```
0 :  [1, [2, 3, [4], []], [5]]
     /           \         
1 : 1    [[2, 3, [4], []], [5]]
              /              \
2 :     [2, 3, [4], []]     [[5]]
        /        \            | \
3 :    2     [3, [4], []]    [5] []
             /      |        / \
4 :         3   [[4], []]   5  []
                 /     \
5 :            [4]     [[]]    
               / \      /\
6 :           4  []   []  []
```

Each split here is between `l[0]` on the left and `l[1:]` on the right. As you can see, the branch where `5` is found is separate to the branch which explores `[2, 3, [4], []]` and finds the empty list `[]`.

---

Note that e.g. `ininstance(l, int)` is generally preferred to `type(l) is int`.

Comment: the head of the list on level 2 should read `[2, 3, [4], []]` (the first bracket is not needed)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the following few modifications

```
def recursive_sum(l):
    if type(l) is int:     # If an int, just return the value
        return l
    elif not l:            # If an empty list, return 0
        return 0
    else:           # recursively call this function, and sum the returned values
        return sum(recursive_sum(i) for i in l)
```

Testing

```
>>> a = [1, [2, 3, [4], []], [5]]
>>> recursive_sum(a)
15
```

Comment: I would make the elif only check for list, and then either return 0 or do the recursive call based on an if-test inside it. Then you can use the final else in the type checking to throw an error if the type is not int or list. A bit more readable (IMHO) and definetely more safe. But I guess it might be considered nit-picking for such a simple problem ;)

Comment: the poster is trying to understand recursion in general.